# Erlang Kernel Space Polling

Tags: erlang, elixir

I just want to know if `kqueue` for FreeBSD and `epoll` for Linux and other kernel space polling functions are a default OS behaviour to handle sockets and connections ?

I asked that because I have read the source code of the Erlang Network Driver Section that handle tcp requests and there was any `kqueue` or `epoll` or something like that to poll events that came from sockets

Answer (score 1):

According to the blog post [I/O polling options in OTP 21](https://www.erlang.org/blog/io-polling/), starting in Erlang/OTP 21.0 whether kernel poll will be used is decided at compile time (in earlier versions, you could explicitly activate it by passing the `+K` command line option). As I understand it, it will default to on as long as your system supports it.

You can check whether kernel poll is activated with `system_info`:

```
> erlang:system_info(kernel_poll).
true
```

Comment: Yeah thank you I had read this before, but my question in fact  is : if the kernel space poll is enabled in Erlang/OTP, that means the kernel wil ```epoll``` or ```kqueue``` automatically when creating binding listening and accepting connections without specifiying it's behaviour via code ? because there is no Kernel polling function in the Erlang Network Driver so I hope you understand my question

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`erl_poll.c`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/erts/emulator/sys/common/erl_poll.c) in the Erlang/OTP sources.